# Is there any identity for Levi-Civita contracting with 4 vectors?

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus

Is there any identity to simplify

$$\epsilon_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}A^{\mu}B^{\nu}C^{\rho}D^{\sigma}$$

without explicitly putting into the indices?

Comment: Nope.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: See above eq 2 of hep-ph/9302280.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The result must be proportional to the determinant of $\mathbf{T} =\mathbf{A} \otimes\mathbf{B}\otimes\mathbf{C}\otimes\mathbf{D}$. See the [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) page of Levi-Civita symbol.